# CakePHP find comments along with user data

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am currently implementing comments for my web application, my tables are as follows...

Project HABTM User
User HABTM Project,
Project has many comments,
User has many comments,
comments belong to user,
comments belong to project

the comments table has 2 foreign keys ( user_id, project_id ), i have successfully been able to display all the comments relating to a particular project but i also need the user data along with the comments so i can display the username that posted the comment etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to elaborate the table struct a bit more.

Comment: Im not sure how i can, i've outlined all the relationships, basically a project has members(users) each of these members can post a comment, when a comment is posted(created) the comment text and the id of the project and user it belongs to are added to the comment table as foreign keys, what i want to do is, when i'm inside a project pull all the comments and related users using the project id of the project i am currently within, hope this helps thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will try to outline a working example:

TABLES:

- **Projects**
- **Users**
- **Comments**
- **User_In_Project**

FIELDS:

- **Projects**: IdProject (PK), Name, etc.
- **Users**: IdUser (PK), Name, Username, etc.
- **User_In_Project**: IdUserProject (PK), IdUser (FK), IdProject (FK), etc.
- **Comments**: IdComment (PK), IdUserProject (FK from User_In_Project), Text, etc.

Comment: this is the table structure i currently have, what i need help with is the find function, currently to pull the comments for a particular project i use  $comments = $this->Comment->find('all', array('conditions' => array('project_id' => $projectId))); but this only pulls the comments from the db, no related user data.

Comment: @user3196052 well, the problem is, comments should not link to projects table, rather to user_in-project, which is the table representing the HABTM relationship.

Comment: no worries. just remember, everytime you have a many-to-many, an association table might be in order :D Usually you don't need a PK in that one, the two FK's should do the trick, but in this case it is useful for linking the comment to the user_in_project